# SSL certificate error when installing Python cx_Oracle from PyPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

I need to connect to Oracle 11g express edition. For that I had tried to install cx-Oracle using the command pip install cx-Oracle. My python version is:   Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 4.1.0 (64-bit).

It was showing error

> Collecting cx-Oracle
>    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/cx-oracle/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
>    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cx-Oracle (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for cx-Oracle

I also tried

```
conda install -c amodig cx_oracle
```

It was also showing an compatible error :

> The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>    - cx_oracle
>    - python 3.5*
>   Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

What Oracle version should ? install? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You're using an old-ish version of Python and an obsolete version of Oracle. Any reason why you can't use [Oracle 18 XE](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html)? There's even a nice [Docker image for it](https://github.com/fuzziebrain/docker-oracle-xe). The latest version of cx_oracle is compatible with Oracle 11gR2 but I'm not sure that includes 11g XE compatibility. Also [have you read the installation guide](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html)

Comment: A lot of companies use obsolete versions of Oracle - my employer, for one. But we're upgrading to 18c Real Soon Now...

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - XE which makes me think this is not an organisational limitation. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with cx_Oracle, try adding this to your pip command:
--trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org